# How to make handle submit in onchangetext react native

Tags: react-native, lodash, textinput, debouncing

I have a project mobile application, and I have a little problem. So, I want to make FORM without button save, data is saved when the user types. So, I try using debounce in lodash but there are still issues that the last letter is typed keywords are not saved. Example: I typing "beautiful" then only saved "beautifu". My code like this:

```
import { debounce } from "lodash"
const [text, setText] = useState("")


const handleSubmit = async () => {
............................
............................
}

const handler = debounce(async () => await handleSubmit(), 1000)

const onChangeText = async (value) => {
  setText(value)
  await handler()
}

<TextInput
  value={text}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  style={styles.input}
  underlineColor={"#ededed"}
  theme={{ colors: { primary: "#ededed" } }}
  selectionColor={"#0f9ed1"}
/>
```

So, anyone help me for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the text value directly on your handleSubmit:

```
import { debounce } from "lodash"
const [text, setText] = useState("")


const handleSubmit = async (value) => {
............................
............................
}

const handler = debounce(async (value) => await handleSubmit(value), 1000)

const onChangeText = async (value) => {
  setText(value)
  await handler(value)
}

<TextInput
  value={text}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  style={styles.input}
  underlineColor={"#ededed"}
  theme={{ colors: { primary: "#ededed" } }}
  selectionColor={"#0f9ed1"}
/>
```

You are not getting the latest character because the state is not already updated with the latest value when you call handleSubmit.

A better way to handle this use case could be with useEffect:

```
import { debounce } from "lodash"
const [text, setText] = useState("")


useEffect(()=>{
    (async ()=>{
        await handler(value)
    })()
},[text])

const handleSubmit = async (value) => {
............................
............................
}

const handler = debounce(async (value) => await handleSubmit(value), 1000)

const onChangeText = (value) => {
  setText(value)
}

<TextInput
  value={text}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  style={styles.input}
  underlineColor={"#ededed"}
  theme={{ colors: { primary: "#ededed" } }}
  selectionColor={"#0f9ed1"}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [text, setText] = useState("")

<TextInput
  value={text}
  onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
  style={styles.input}
/>
```